# Adding button to the custom dialog's layout(dialog.xml)

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, customdialog

Thanks for the answers guys, After following your replies i somehow managed to get something like this from the following code, But still i have some more fixes.Please try to help.
[image]

dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView1" >
    </ListView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#FFFFBB33"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/alert_dialog_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listViewDialog"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Categories"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxAll"
        android:text="All"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add buttons below your relative layout (I mean - into another parent layout)?

Comment: you mean a relative layout inside a relative layout.?

Comment: I mean making one new parent layout and putting in it two other layouts: 1) your current layour 2) your layout with buttons

Comment: please check my question for edits. thank you.

Comment: Change android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" to android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"

Comment: And why have you created a new linearlayout? you have kept the button outside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="OK"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

in Android Cracker's code.

Comment: I am getting the button from your code, but there is no proper alignment, i have edited my question again, please do check.?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one ,I have modified your layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1" >
</ListView>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="center"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listViewDialog"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Categories"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxAll"
    android:text="All"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="OK"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Comment: I tried with your code, but still some issues are left to solve. I have pasted the screenshot. See my edited questiom.

Comment: Can you elaborate properly how you want design you layout , so i will help you?

Comment: i just want to remove the space between the list view and the button in the dialog. That is all i want.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910301/android-custom-dialog-inflating-from-layout-alignment-issue

Comment: I think, you need give fixed height to listview instead of wrap_content ,and remove android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" from button tag ,that's it