# Android Custom dialog inflating from layout - alignment issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, customdialog

I have an custom dialog, whick i am inflating from dialog.xml. when I open the dialog it looks something like shown below. I am getting some space between listview and the (OK) button below it. I want to eliminate this space between the list view and the Button below it.
How can i do this,?

[image]

dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView1" >
    </ListView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#FFFFBB33"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/alert_dialog_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listViewDialog"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Categories"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxAll"
        android:text="All"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set following attribute to the button: `android:layout_below="@id/textView2"` ?

Edit: You have to remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`if you try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is really easy.. 
you have 2 approchase:
1) create the root realtivelayout to have android:layout_height="wrap_cotent", and in the same time the ListView to have the same. this will shrink the sizes of the all dialog to the right (no space) size.
2) *more recomended , have the root to be a Linearlayout and give it some wightsum, then put the other views in this root, and give them some layout_wight, this way you know the in any screen resolution you have the same porportion of your screen.

Comment: ill explain, its a bit out of the scope of programming - think ui design; if you "button" is depanded on the list size - if the list is big, you wont see him.. if the list is small, he will be set in the mybe middle of the screen (depend how small the list is..) this is not "right" behivor.. you should rether have a button which is in on place.. (maybe even on top of the page), and let the list to be scrolled in its own zone.. (depanding static and dynmaic views in a layout is allmost always bad design).

Answer (score 0):

```
maybe try like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="15" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBoxAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#FFFFBB33"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/listViewDialog"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Categories"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBoxAll"
                android:text="All"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewDialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="70" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="15" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="OK" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```